# After effects and Hyperlinks

Tags: html, after-effects

I am trying to add a hyperlink in an After Effects composition so that when the animation plays that you can click on it to jump to a hyperlink. I have tried placing the hyperlink inside a marker in the composition but once rendered, nothing seems to be working.

Basically trying to recreate the link overlays that people add to their youtube clips. Any help?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. In youtube things like annotations are possible because of the *player*. The video itself has nothing to do with them. They are added after it has been uploaded.

Comment: Sorry - I think I am being confusing. Yes, I understand the annotations that people place over their videos in youtube - I am trying to mimic that in After Effects, but not actually use the annotations - I am looking for a work around. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: There is nothing mature to do this that works on all platforms except for HTML5 + JS.

In After Effects itself this is not possible. You could use Flash. But that means that your recipient needs to have a flash player on his machine.

In ancient times you could also create interactive Videos with [QuickTime Pro 7](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL923?locale=de_DE&viewlocale=de_DE) e.g. like in [this tutorial](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=758432&seqNum=3) but it never moved out of the QT and nobody cared. It is bound to the platform (macOS) and the player (QT).

In 2003  Matthew R. Peterson wrote a book about it [Authoring Wired Media (QuickTime Developer Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607463) and it sounds like "the next big thing".

Answer (score 0):

You should use `markers` in after effect.
When you render a composition that contains markers, the markers can be converted to web links, chapter links (chapter points), or cue points, depending on the output format and values that you set in the marker dialog box. Markers can also be exported as XMP metadata. (See XMP metadata.)

See this [resource](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-markers-composition-markers.html#WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7e64a)